# How to recreate this effect from Apple's GameCenter?

Tags: gimp

How could I recreate the background and the effect on the ribbons, borders, and "Other" text in this screenshot from Apple's GameCenter app?  To me, the background looks a little glittery, but also a bit like felt, while the other parts look kind of like they have been painted on, with some of the texture coming through.

I am using Gimp, but can usually follow basic Photshop tutorials pretty well, if they don't rely too much on effects Gimp doesn't support.

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot image]

[Larger image here](http://bit.ly/xfGgWN).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effects look like they were using an Overlay blending mode on textures or vice versa. For instance, the background felt could be a stock image or made with some noise filters. The graphics or lettering was then placed and and when they were happy with the placement, used a blending mode and mask to make the final look.

Photoshop instructions
1. Get the textures for each graphic
2. mask the part of the graphic you would like to be textured
3. use blending modes such as overlay, multiply.. etc
4. take that final image and create your layout

I believe it's the blending modes for your painted effect. The fact there is no solid color they either used stock textures or made them through a noise filter or pattern as the bottom of the user card appears.

Comment: Thanks for the response, and for un-breaking my link, Stefan.  I managed to create the background using a base color, adding noise, blurring, bump mapping, and using some different layer effects.  I was able to create something reasonably close to the other parts using 3 identical layers, one each with layer mode Saturation, Overlay, and Color.  A little shinier than I wanted, though.  Results here: bit.ly/wP8bak

Answer (score 0):

Background effect is simply matter of having couple of layers with one have monochromatic noise and emboss + using a colour filter to get the greenish tint.

Also I can see some sort of radial gradient in the middle (which is a bit lighter than the edges)

Ribbons are stock shapes (unless someone did it by hand) you should be able to source this from the web, I am sure there are zillions available for free.

Same filter that is used for the green background is also applied on all the ribbons - thats why you see the grainy effect on them.

I can write you a step by step process when I have a bit more time.

Comment: Hasan, thanks for your reply.  I'm not too worried about the ribbons or shapes, but just how the colors in the UI elements were accomplished.  What I was able to make ended up being shiny, while the originals were kind of matte.  Also, the green from the background seemed to come through a bit.  So if you have any more advice I would appreciate it!